# How much time for writing a 6.000 words paper?

Tags: paper-submission, working-time

How much time should I take into account for writing a 6.000 words (captions and references included) academic paper, considering that the analysis has been completed?

Thanks

Comment: How are _we_ supposed to know how fast you write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Budget 1-2 hours.
2. Start writing.
3. Set up a timer. Stop when time is up, pause when you took a break.
4. When time is up, look at the lower left corner of your word processor (I use MS Words on Window) you'll see "Words: ###".
5. Divide 6000 by that number, then multiply by the hours you just spent.
6. The answer is the estimated total time.
7. I'd suggest adding 10%-25% more time to that for revising, formatting, and final proofread. (Notice that the time needed depends on the quality of the first draft. Some might suggest 10 - 25 times for these purposes. Your mileage may differ.)
8. In addition, keep a log for every writing session, track if you're on par with the goal. Adjust your time needed accordingly. Do not attempt to binge write. Binge writing 6000 words can be error prone and tiring.

Comment: I suggest adding 1000%-2500% for revising, formatting, and final proofreading.

Comment: @DavidZwicker, thanks, I added your point to the answer.

Comment: I fully agree with @DavidZwicker - if you want a good paper, the rewriting and rewriting and rewriting is the time consuming portion. First drafts of technical papers are, well, lousy. Any author, technical or otherwise, spends far more time rewriting than anything else.